# Power series radius of convergence equal to r, nonzero for every number meeting conditions

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have been stuck on this question for a few hours now. It seems like it should be simple, but for some reason I can not figure out a solid proof. It seems like a simple series proof, but the $a$ is really throwing me off especially at the end of the problem.

"Let $a$,$c_0$,$c_1$,$c_2$,... be in R, with at least one of $c_0$,$c_1$,$c_2$,... nonzero. Let the power series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n $$

have positive radius of convergence $r$. Show that there exists a positive number $w$ < $r$ such that the sum of the series is nonzero for every real number $x$ such that 0 < |$x$ - $a$| < $w$."

**EDIT:** The attempted solution: A proof by contradiction showing that all coefficients $c_i$ = 0 for i = 0,1,2,3,....

assume such a delta does not exist. For all $n$ there exists $x_n$ such that 0 < |$x_n$ - $a$| < $1/n$.

we note that $f$ is continuous in ($a-r, a+r$) and the limit of $x_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity is equal to $a$.

In the taylor expansion $c_0$ = $f(a)$ = lim $f(x_n)$ as $n$ approaches infinity which is equal to the lim 0 as $n$ approaches infinity, which equals zero. So, $c_0$ = 0.

Let us now look at $c_1$. $$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_n(x-a)^n $$
$$ =(x-a) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n+1}(x-a)^n $$, we let this be a new series and write $l(x) =(x-a) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n+1}(x-a)^n $. $l(x)$ has the same radius of convergence and $l(x_n)$ = 0 since $f(x_n)$ = 0. Thus, the first term $c_1$ = $g(a)$ = 0.

Let us now use induction to show that $c_{n+1}$ = 0. 
$$ =(x-a)^{n+1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n+1}(x-a)^n $$

Let $g(x) = (x-a)^{n+1} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{n+1}(x-a)^n $ 
Then, $c_{n+1}$ = $g(a)$ = 0. 
Thus, all coefficients go to zero. Proof by contradiction.

I am not sure if my induction logic is correct. Some help on that would be great.

Comment: Does the ["principle of isolated zeros"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_(complex_analysis)#Properties) (or a similar name) ring a bell?

Comment: It does not, I am self-studying through a real analysis book right now and have not come across it yet

Comment: Your proof may be on the right track, I'm not sure, but I'm having trouble understanding it. First of all, $n$ is your index of summation, so it does not make sense to multiply by $(x-a)^{n+1}$ outside the sum, nor does it make sense to talk about $c_{n+1}$ outside of the sum, unless $n$ is a fixed index, in which case it cannot be your index variable. I put the proof I would use in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint*: Suppose $c_n$ is the first nonzero coefficient. The basic idea is that close to $a$, the $(x-a)^n$ term should matter much more than all higher terms put together, since the series converges.

*Hint #2*: If $c_n$ is the first nonzero coefficient, divide by $(x-a)^n$ and show that you can get all the rest of the terms to be less than the constant coefficient $c_n$ (in modulus).

The proof I would use is below:

First part:

> **Proof:** Suppose first that $c_0$ is nonzero. Then the function $f(x) - c_0 = \sum_{i=1}^\infty c_i (x-a)^i$ is continuous, and it is zero at $a$, so there is a neighborhood of $a$ on which $|f(x) - c_0| < |c_0|$, and then $f$ cannot be zero anywhere inside this neighborhood, because $|f(x)| = |f(x) - c_0 + c_0| \geq \left||c_0| - |f(x) - c_0| \right|\geq |c_0| - |f(x) - c_0| > |c_0| - |c_0| = 0$. (I wrote out this inequality in detail in case you have trouble with it, but it should be intuitive that if $|f(x)-c_0|$ is small then $f(x)$ can't get to zero).

Main part:

> Now for the proof of the main claim: if $c_n$ is the first nonzero coefficient, note that $\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^n}$ is a power series whose coefficients have the same radius of convergence (Cauchy-Hadamard theorem), and except at $a$ where it is undefined, it is a power series whose constant term is nonzero. So there is a punctured neighborhood of $a$ on which $\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^n}$ is nonzero. But on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{a\}$, we have that $\frac{f(x)}{(x-a)^n}$ is zero iff $f(x)$ is. So $f$ is nonzero on the punctured neighborhood of $a$ and we are done.

Comment: hmmm I'll think about this, but I am not seeing how to approach it immediately yet

Comment: @TonyFridder Try this

Comment: It might help to simplify the problem: Try proving this first: if $c_0 \ne 0$, then $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n \ne 0$ for $0 < |x| < w$ for some w. Once you have figured that out by Eric's excellent hints, generalizing it the statement you actually need should be easy.

Comment: I see the first hint, but the second one is not making sense to me on how to go about proving it :/

Comment: @TonyFridder Suppose that $c_0$ is nonzero. Can you prove that the power series stays away from zero in a neighborhood of $a$? (Can you show that the other terms stay close to zero in a neighborhood of $a$? Use the continuity of the function defined by the rest of the terms, and remember the rest of the terms are zero at $a$.)

Comment: I will try this, if I don't respond in 45 mins I am still working on it thanks for the hints :)

Comment: @TonyFridder If your proof is long, you're working too hard. :-) The proof is not much longer than what I wrote...I think it's just about understanding what I said above.

Comment: I used a proof by contradiction and got c0 = 0,  c1= 0, but I think I need to do induction now on it, but it's not coming out right

Comment: Please see edit @EricAuld